# Pipelining and instruction cycle

Tags: computer-architecture

Consider the sequence of machine instruction given below:
\begin{array}{ll} \text{MUL} & \text{R5, R0, R1} \\  \text{DIV} & \text{R6, R2, R3} \\   \text{ADD} & \text{R7, R5, R6} \\  \text{SUB} & \text{R8, R7, R4}  \\ \end{array}

In  the above sequence, $R0$ to $R8$ are general purpose registers. In the instructions shown, the first register shows the result of the operation performed on the second and the third registers. This sequence of instructions is to be executed in a pipelined instruction processor with the following $4$ stages: $(1)$ Instruction Fetch and Decode $(IF)$, $(2)$ Operand Fetch $(OF)$, $(3)$ Perform Operation $(PO)$ and $(4)$ Write back the result $(WB)$. The $IF, OF$ and $WB$ stages take $1$ clock cycle each for any instruction. The $PO$ stage takes $1$ clock cycle for $ADD$ and $SUB$ instruction, $3$ clock cycles for $MUL$ instruction and $5$ clock cycles for $DIV$ instruction. The pipelined processor uses operand forwarding from the $PO$ stage to the $OF$ stage. The number of clock cycles taken for the execution of the above sequence of instruction is _________.

I got the answer as 15 however the correct answer is 13. Am I doing something wrong or is the answer key at fault?
The link for reference: https://gateoverflow.in/8218/gate2015-2-44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the sentence "The pipelined processor uses operand forwarding from the PO stage to the OF stage". That means if a result is written at cycle n, the same result can be read as an operand at the same cycle n. This happens twice in your instruction sequence. If you ignore this, your count will be too high by two.

Comment: could you please give me a solution so I could understand it better?

Comment: Did you understand what "operand forwarding from the PO stage to the OF stage" means?

Comment: yes I am aware of the concept of operator forwarding  but wouldn't that mean: OF can execute as soon as PO is over?

Comment: OF can execute as soon as PO is over even without operator forwarding. Operator forwarding means that _in the same cycle_, the data can be sent _both_ to the register where it should be stored, AND to the operand that needs it. We are taking a shortcut, that in this case saves 2 of 15 cycles; about 15% more performance.

Comment: Alright now I understand why my answer was coming all wrong. Anyway if it was just mentioned that operating forwarding is used (not specifically mentioning that between PO and OF) would we still consider that it is possible to jump from PO to OF?

Comment: In that case, you would consider that whoever asked the question was horribly imprecise. But forwarding only makes sense from "perform operation" to "operand fetch". So I would write the same answer, but start with "Assuming that message forwarding is from PO to OF stage: "

Comment: @gnasher729 you say that `forwarding only makes sense from "perform operation" to "operand fetch".` But I have read _Computer Organization and Design, by Patterson et. al_ where they show how the operands are forwarded from various section after the EX phase to the inputs of the ALU using MUX. (3rd edition. pg 405,408,409). The convention used in the patterson book is clearly explained. What is creating problem here is that the question says PO to OF, which makes me naturally feel that we give the output of the ALU to the inputs of the OF (literal meaning guessed from the question).(continued)

Comment: @gnasher729 Now in the solution to the question they are using some sort of split phasing using again used in patterson, only for the register read phase and the register write back phase, to prevent structural hazard.  How is the operand forwarding from the PO phase to the OF phase being executed? As you say that the data from the ALU is written to the latch following the ALU and also to the latch preceding the ALU and following the OF stage in a single cycle.. The effect being similar to the result of ALU being forwarded to the inputs of the ALU. ( The case explained in patterson)(continued)

Comment: @gnasher729 From the convention used in Patterson, what I felt after reading the question is, the output of the ALU is being sent to the input of OF stage and in the next clock cycle there is simultaneous WB of the value to the register file and at the same time we can read the operand (if required) from the latch following the ALU in the OF stage. And this made me get 15 cycles. Now as per your concept, `Operator forwarding means that in the same cycle, the data can be sent both to the register where it should be stored, AND to the operand that needs it.` I am wrong. (continued)

Comment: @gnasher729 I do not quite get it as to when to apply what and it is quite confusing. Could you please provide the source from where developed your concepts or atleast those which shall help me understand it. Moreover, they are using split phase for the question, solve a question with so much assumptions in less than 3 mins is quite trouble some. https://drive.google.com/file/d/19yWwrPU01c9ct1ICcHfZzMqHSTz3ittQ/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y6cly2tHJ2dgPN8sa5531xKhyC6nc9i_/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oET4pwjHB9LmlLzzKxf2LOkWjNrfMFpJ/view?usp=sharing